# How to echo a statement based on the result of the previous echo

Tags: shell

Lets say I want something like this

```
echo a | b | c | d
echo e
```

I have to `echo e` only when there is any output for first echo (`echo a | b | c | d`).

How to do this?

Comment: @fedorqui No. To quote `man bash` _"The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the **last** command,
       unless the **pipefail** option is enabled."_ Moreover the question here is not about the "return status", but the "output"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use if statement on the result of pipes, to check the output is empty or not?

```
if  [[ $(a | b | c | d) != "" ]] ; then
```

In this way you capture the output of `a | b | c | d` into a string and check if it's empty or not, if not then you can continue with your next command e (or actually `echo e`)

Comment: `-ne` is for _numeric_ comparison. String comparison should used the `!=` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Sometime it is not suitable to hold the entire result in a var (because it is too large, or because you want "live" output). In that case, maybe you can try a "clever" use of `tee` instead:

```
echo a | b | c | d | tee >([ `wc -l` -gt 0 ] && echo e)
```

Instead of "counting lines", you might prefer "counting chars" (that won't chop in your output do *not* contains newline characters:

```
echo a | b | c | d | tee >([ `wc -c` -gt 0 ] && echo e)
```

If a single "empty line" terminated by an end-of-line character must be considered as an "empty" output, you should check for an output greater than 1 instead.